# NetworkStatus0 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using cordova-1.6.1 on Mac Lion with Xcode 4.3.1. I'm getting following error

CordovaApp[322:13403] [INFO] Error in success callback: NetworkStatus0 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

when following line is executed.

navigator.network.isReachable("phonegap.com", reachableCallback, {});

A function is defined as follows

```
function reachableCallback(reachability) {
  var networkState = reachability.code;
  alert('Connection type: ' + networkState + ' - ' + reachability.message);
}
```

I'm unable to figure this out for a quite some time. Please help

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isReachable method has been deprecated out of PhoneGap. You are better off looking at the new Network features like the online and offline events. As well looking at:

```
navigator.network.connection.type
```

Will tell you what type of network connection you currently have or None if there is no connection.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I've used navigator.network.connection.type and it solve my problem.