# "NetworkStatus0 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function" Error Without Reason

Tags: javascript, ios, networking, cordova

I have a new Cordova (aka PhoneGap) project for iOS which is using the jQuery method `$.getJSON` to interact with a RESTful API, which is running on a test server. The problem is that when I try to run the application I get this on my Xcode debug log:

> 2012-05-01 11:10:49.031 RESTtest[223:707] [INFO] Error in success callback: NetworkStatus0 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

I've done some searching about this error and I went across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371986/networkstatus0-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function), but the problem is that I'm not using `navigator.network.isReachable`, neither `navigator.network.connection.type`, since it's just a test project. What is wrong and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer as it is a technique to help you get the answer - first thing you need to do is figure out which line is throwing the error.  try commenting out chunks of code until you figure out which line of code is causing the problem.  Often this will give you a much clearer idea of what's going on - and if not, it'll let you know which code blocks to quote to help *us* figure out what's going on.

My guess, just from parsing the error, is that somehow in the success callback from one of your calls over to the test server, you're either calling a function that isn't properly defined, or the javascript parser thinks you're trying to call a function where you aren't.  In my experience, either of these can come out of (for example) dropping a parenthesis in the wrong place, or similar typos - and catching them is a lot easier after you've used the "comment out and re-run" trick to narrow down exactly where.